# c# move point along an arc

Tags: c#

Please see this picture:

I need to move by mouse one of the two points along an arc of 90°

Please have in mind that I can rotate the Arrow and the whole thing will rotate as well.

What I did:

```
public override bool HandleMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{      
   double angleRad = 0;
   double new_cx = 0;
   double new_cY = 0;
   double currentAngle = Arrow.Rotation.Angle;
   Point pt = TMEMControl.ScreenToWorld(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
   Point center = TMEMControl.ScreenToWorld(new Point(Arrow.Translation.X, Arrow.Translation.Y));                        
   Point c = new Point(center.X + 25, center.Y);

   angleRad = (-currentAngle) * (Math.PI / 180);
   new_cx = center.X + Math.Cos(angleRad) * 25;
   new_cY = center.Y + Math.Sin(angleRad) * 25;
   c = new Point(new_cx, new_cY);

   Vector CenterPt = new Vector((pt.X-center.X),(pt.Y-center.Y));
   Vector CenterC = new Vector((c.X - center.X),(c.Y - center.Y));
   fieldOfView = Vector.AngleBetween(CenterPt, CenterC);

   if (fieldOfView >= 90) fieldOfView = 90;
   if (fieldOfView <= 0) fieldOfView = 0;

   TMEMControl.Settings.VideoOverlayHelper.FieldOfView = (float)SmartFrame.Basic.BaseAngle.Deg2Rad(fieldOfView*2);

   updateFieldofView = (float)fieldOfView;

   if (updateFieldofView > 87) updateFieldofView = 87;
   if (updateFieldofView < 0) updateFieldofView = 0;
   return true;
}

public void Reset(int id, double x, double y, double angle)
{  
   double angleInRadians = 0;
   Point center = new Point(x + 15, y + 20);
   Point refP = new Point(x + 15, (y - 80));         
   distance = Point.Subtract(refP, center).Length;
   double new_x = 0;
   double new_y = 0;
   ControlPoint cpi = CameraCtrl.getCP(id);
   if (null != cpi)
   {
      switch (id)
      {
      case 0:
         cpi.point = new Point(center.X, center.Y);
         cpi.state = ControlPoint.States.Selectable;
         break;
      case 1:
         cpi.point = new Point(x + 15, (y + 80));             
         angleInRadians = (float)SmartFrame.Basic.BaseAngle.Deg2Rad((angle + (87 - updateFieldofView)));
         new_x = center.X + Math.Cos(-angleInRadians) * distance;
         new_y = center.Y + Math.Sin(-angleInRadians) * distance;              
         cpi.point = new Point(new_x, new_y);               
         cpi.state = ControlPoint.States.Fixed;             
         break;
      case 2:
         cpi.point = new Point(x + 15, (y - 80));
         angleInRadians = (float)SmartFrame.Basic.BaseAngle.Deg2Rad((angle + (180 - (87 - updateFieldofView))));
         new_x = center.X + Math.Cos(-angleInRadians) * distance;
         new_y = center.Y + Math.Sin(-angleInRadians) * distance;
         cpi.point = new Point(new_x, new_y);
         cpi.state = ControlPoint.States.Selectable;
         break;
      }            
   }
}
```

It's working 90% the problem is that once I snap/click on one of the red dots and move the mouse, the red dot is always few degrees ahead from the the mouse cursor. and I need to move it with the cursor Position.

And just for the info why I set always the angle to max 87°, is because I want to keep a little distance between the Arrow and my two lines.

Comment: I need to mention one other thing, this code is part of a bigger program in our office, I don't know why but the way the coordinate system is made the horizontal is the Y axis pointing to the left and the vertical pointing up is the X axis. so basically   in a "normal" coordinate system -X = Y and Y=X.

Comment: Modify your `updateFieldofView` limits to go from -90° to +90°, not 0° to 90°. If you use your method, clicking below the camera's Y position will give you a negative angle, since `atan2` has a range of -180° to +180°. Your code will clamp any negative values to 0°.

Comment: All of this assumes that your CameraPosition is in screen coordinates (horizontal X, vertical Y) rather than the rotated coordinate system you mentioned. (Since that is the convention your mouse coordinates are using.)

Comment: will try your tip with -90 to 90 but unfortunately  the CamerPosition in in screen coordination (Vertical X, Horizontal Y) and like I said normal coordinate (horizontal X, vertical Y) X = -y and Y = x

Comment: That's just rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise. So, change the clamp to go from 0 to 180, or -180 to 0. Or, just remove the check for the moment. You also need to make sure that you're either converting the camera position to screen space, or the mouse position to your local rotated coordinate system before doing all the arithmetic. If you do that, then you'd still go with the -90 to +90 range.

Comment: Thanks 3Dave, changing the Cursor Postion  to my (World) Coordinate System, seems to have partially resolved the issue. Unfortunately not 100% I still have the problem that the Points/Dots are always few degrees ahead from the mouse Cursor. Please see the updates code Above –

Comment: new update (code above) now the gab between the dot selected and the cursor postion is much more less! About 1 degree. Also by only clicking on the dot and releasing it without moving the the dot jumps ahead also about 1 degree. 2nd problem now; it's working only if I select the red dot at the bottom of the camera, however if I select and move the one on top, the 2 points are only moving if I move the cursor in the opposit direction. Assuming the camera is set like int picture above by moving the cursor down, the red dot on top moves up and if I move the cursor up the red dot on Top moves down

Comment: That could be a precision issue. Since the pixels have a non-zero area, any calculation result is ultimately going to get clamped to the closest pixel. You could offset your mouse coordinates (`e.xy`) by `(0.3,0.3)` pixels to help that. Does your `Point` structure have integer or float (or double) coordinates? You'll want to keep everything as floats.